# I need to write a filter function (I think) that returns a unique "ID" only if all "Type" ="b"

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, unique

ID  Type
124  a
124  b
125  a
125  a
125  b
126  b
126  b
126  b
126  b
127  b
127  a

Results:
126

Comment: Why results should be only `126` for `b`? There is `125` & `127` as well

Comment: Why not 127?  There is a row where type is B

Comment: BTW, the explanation should not be in the title or comments, but in the question itself.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes, I was trying to preempt them try to explain in the comments.   This is a poor question as the question only has the data and not an explanation of what they tried, what failed and what they want in the question body.

Comment: Yes even in the beginning it was hard to understand, but minutely watching the data i realized what OP was looking for hence didnt wait for anything just answered it.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the count of `B` is the same as the countof the ID:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A12,COUNTIF(A2:A12,A2:A12)=COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,"b")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*If I have understood correctly, this should work as per the given conditions: --> Returning Unique ID's only if all the occurrences are **type = "b"***

[image]

---

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A12,
 COUNTIFS(A2:A12, A2:A12,B2:B12, "<>b") = 0))
```

---

Sample Test:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, A2:A12,
     UNIQUE(FILTER(α,COUNTIFS(α, α,B2:B12, "<>b") = 0)))
```

---

- Using `COUNTIFS()` function counting the number of occurrences where both the values in `ID` Column & `Type` Column is not equal to `b`
- Only taking those rows where the `ID` has only `Type` --> `b` other than that no occurrences of the same `ID` has no other types. Therefore, to keep those doing a boolean logic. `COUNTIFS()=0`
- Next using `FILTER()` to include only those rows where it meets the above conditions.
- Lastly, wrapping within `UNIQUE()` to exclude duplicates. For reference check the sample test screenshot.

---

Answer (score 1):

The logical steps to do this would be:

1. Use the "UNIQUE" function to list all unique 'ID' values from Column A.
2. Use the "FILTER" function to limit the results from Column B to only "b" (or uppercase B, since that's technically different).
3. Use the "COUNTIFS" function to count how many times each unique value from Column A occurs -- AND -- how many times b/B occurs in Column B.
4. Only return the value in Column A if the count from Column A equals the count from Column B.

Since Excel can't handle nested arrays, you're probably better off creating helper columns for each of the steps above. So...

- Col C: `=COUNTIFS(A:A, A1, B:B, "b")`
  This will return the number of times "b" occurs in Col B. for each value of A1 in all of Col A. So for rows 1 and 2, which are both 124, Col B will display 1, since "b" occurs 1 time after "124" (row 2).
- Col D: `=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)`
  This will return the number of times the value in Col A occurs in all of Col A.
- Col E: `=IF(C1 = D1, A1, "")`
  This will return the value in A1 only if the number of "b" from Col C matches the number of that value from Col D, meaning that for every value of this A1, Col B was always "b".
- Col F: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,E:E<>""))`
  This will return a list of each value from Col A where every value in Col B was "b"

It's perhaps not the prettiest of solutions, but it's going to give you ar more reliable results than trying to force all of those calculations into a single formula.